# How to target an Ngrx/Store in Protractor

Tags: angular, protractor, e2e-testing

I currently have an E2E test which I have written using protractor. I am currently using async await as follows:

```
it('should check master checkbox, when master checkbox is clicked on', async() => {
  await page.navigateTo();
  await page.toggleMasterCheckbox();
  expect(await page.determineIfMasterCheckboxIsChecked()).toEqual(1);
});
```

However, as I have noticed, async await, with regards to the click event, is not checking to make sure that the store observable has properly emitted, and that checkbox has been displayed in the "master" checkbox. Any suggestions, as to how I can target my store in my E2E test, so that I can attach an await event to it, would be more than appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue had to do with fact that event listener was not returned in function call. I would guess that caused function not to bind to await as expected. Once event listener returned in function digest(,or zone.run) happened as expected.